Maximum Likelihood Estimation based on the sample minimum
I have $x_1, \dots, x_n$ being observations independently drawn from $X \sim Exp(\lambda)$ and I am trying to calculate MLE for $\lambda$, only knowing $s = \min\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$.
I suppose the observations are ordered, thus $x_1 = s$ and $x_2,\dots, x_n > s$. Then
$$L(\lambda|s) = f(s|\lambda) * \prod_{i=2}^n P[X>s|\lambda] = \lambda e^{-\lambda s} * \prod_{i=2}^n e^{-\lambda s} = \lambda e^{-\lambda s} * e^{-(n-1)\lambda s} = \lambda e^{-n\lambda s} $$
$$l(\lambda|s) = \log\lambda - n\lambda s $$
Taking FOC w.r.t to $\lambda$ yields:
$$ \frac{1}{\hat\lambda_{ML}} - ns = 0 \Rightarrow \hat\lambda_{ML} = \frac{1}{ns} $$
The result seems counterintuitive to me. Can you help please if you see any mistakes in the steps? I am not sure whether I have specified the likelihood function correctly

Your question is equivalent to estimating $\lambda$ for a single observation of the minimum order statistic $X_{(1)}$, so it is useful to first determine the distribution of $X_{(1)} = \min_i X_i$.  To this end, as you noted,
$$\Pr[X_{(1)} > x] = \prod_{i=1}^n \Pr[X_i > x] \overset{\text{iid}}{=} \Pr[X > x]^n = (e^{-\lambda x} \mathbb 1 (x > 0))^n = e^{-n \lambda x} \mathbb 1(x > 0).$$  Here we have assumed that $\lambda$ is a rate parameter in accordance with your previous work.
Thus, $X_{(1)} \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(n\lambda)$ and the estimation of $\lambda$ follows the usual maximum likelihood method:
$$\mathcal L(\lambda \mid x_{(1)}) \propto f_{X_{(1)}}(x_{(1)} \mid \lambda) = \lambda e^{-n\lambda x_{(1)}} \mathbb 1(x_{(1)} > 0),$$
hence the log-likelihood is
$$\ell(\lambda \mid x_{(1)}) \propto  \log \lambda - n\lambda x_{(1)} + \log \mathbb 1 (x_{(1)} > 0).$$
When the indicator is satisfied, we have
$$\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \lambda} \propto  \frac{1}{\lambda} -n x_{(1)}$$
and the unique critical point satisfying $\partial \ell/\partial \lambda = 0$ is
$$\hat \lambda = \frac{1}{nx_{(1)}}.$$
This agrees with your computation.  I'm not sure why you think it is counterintuitive; however, be warned that the properties of this estimator are extremely poor.  The estimator is inverse gamma distributed with shape $\alpha = 1$ and rate $\lambda$, with density
$$f_{\hat \lambda}(m) = \frac{\lambda}{m^2} e^{-\lambda/m} \mathbb 1 (m > 0),$$
and as such, it is very heavy-tailed:  the first moment $\operatorname{E}[\hat \lambda]$ is infinite.  Thus it will not converge with repeated sampling, and in fact, this poor behavior occurs irrespective of the size of $n$, as we can see that the density of $\hat \lambda$ is independent of $n$.
